# JavaScript Array Ranking

Tags: javascript

I have an Arrays like below in javascript:

```
var array1 = [10,23,53,74,33,56,6,0,43,45,11];
var array2 = [52,46,27,28,4,11,53,6,75,75,22];
var array3 = [26,18,10,12,31,12,5,8,44,34,65];
...
n number of array
```

So I want these array in Ranking format. Let's say 
array1[0] = 10 
 array2[0] = 52 
 array3[0] = 26 
 so in the above example 52 is the highest value so it will replace as a 1 and 26 is the second highest value it will be replace with 2 and 10 is the third highiest value so it will replace as 3 and so on...
So the result of above example is: 
var array1= [3];
var array2 = [1];
var array3 = [2];

And the whol arrays result will be as below:

```
var array1= [3,2,1,1,1,1,2,3,2,2,3];
var array2= [1,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,1,2];
var array3= [2,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,2,3,1];
...
n number of array
```

I have tried this with creating a parent array and keeping all sub arrays into parent and I have used multiple for loops to iterating sub arrays

Comment: how are the arrays connected? what have you tried?

Comment: is the result just a place on highest value leaderboard?

Comment: What exactly is the end result? I mean what kind of ranking is that? Seems random from what you've provided

Comment: yes, these arrays are independent but have to check first array[0] position with rest of all arrays [0] position if value[0] got first highest in any arrays this value replace  with 1 and second highest value will be replace with 2 and so on

Comment: what about same values? doe they get the same rank?

Comment: @Nina yes, same rank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a chained approach by

- transpose the data,
- map the ranks for each array,
- transpose again.

`transpose` is a litte function which takes an array of arrays and returns the switched values of cols in a row.

`ranks` takes an array, and maps the positions of the sorted array. This function creates inside a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of values with the assigned ranks.

```js
var transpose = (r, a) => a.map((v, i) => [...(r[i] || []), v]),
    ranks = array => array.map(
        Map.prototype.get,
        [...array]
            .sort((a, b) => b - a)
            .reduce((r => (m, v) => m.set(v, (r++, m.get(v)) || r))(0), new Map)
    ),
    array1 = [10, 23, 53, 74, 33, 56, 6, 0, 43, 45, 11],
    array2 = [52, 46, 27, 28, 4, 11, 53, 6, 75, 75, 22],
    array3 = [26, 18, 10, 12, 31, 12, 5, 8, 44, 34, 65],
    result = [array1, array2, array3]
        .reduce(transpose, [])
        .map(ranks)
        .reduce(transpose, []);

result.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It is exactly matching the answer but one problem is there. When the same values is there ranking is coming same and next ranking is staring from as like continues series(It seems like Dense Rank). But the my expectation is next ranking should start from how many same matches + continue ranking.

Comment: do you like to get for `[3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]` this `[1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 6, 6]`?

Comment: Yes, Exactly like this

Comment: Thank yo so much!